# Abrir Programa com arrastando arquivo(PDF) e o mesmo recuperar o caminho

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, drag-n-drop

Ola, Estou com uma necessidade um pouco complicada, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que envia arquivos pdf para uma aplicação via webservices.
Só que quero deixar esse problema inicie de algumas formas diferentes.
Vou tentar explicar com exemplo.
Quando tenho um arquivo em Work e arrasto o mesmo para um atalho o word o mesmo é aberto, e isso acontece com vários programas.
Ou quando vc clica com o botão direito do mouse em um arquivo word e no menu contexto "enviar para " do windows aparece o word e ele abre o arquivo.
Gostaria que a minha aplicação funcionasse desta forma.
Estou trabalhando C# Windows Forms no Visual Studio.
Consegui obter uma função semelhando arrastando o arquivo para o textBox com o Evento DragDrop.
Já pesquisei bastante no Google, mas não sei se estou procurando de forma errada, porque não encontrei nada.
Caso alguém já tenha feito alguma coisa semelhante ou tenha alguma noção de como fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você tratar os argumentos iniciados junto da aplicação. Com isso você pode inclusive chamar a aplicação pela linha de comando, assim:

```
enviarpdf.exe "c:\pdf\arquivo.pdf"
```

para tratar os argumentos, basta declarar um array de string como parâmetro do método `main`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (args.Length != 0)
        {
            string arg = args[0];
            MessageBox.Show(arg);
        }

     }
```

Como sua aplicação é `winforms` e considerando que você precise do caminho dentro do Form1, poderia ser feito assim:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(args.Lenght >0 ? args[0] : null));

     }
```

Assim, o primeiro argumento será repassado ao Form1.

ps. Claro que no Form1, você deve colocar o construtor para receber um parâmetro do tipo string.

```
public Form1(string _arquivo)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ArquivoPdf = _arquivo;
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar implementar

Comment: Funcionou.. Valeu cara, agora só preciso descobrir como criar um atalho do menu "enviar para" do windows recebendo o arquivo, mas valeu mesmo

Comment: blz, eu nunca fiz essa de "enviar para" mas certamente vai estar nos registros do windows. abraços