# Menu Enviar Para do Windows, enviando Caminho do Arquivo

Tags: c#, windows, contexto

Estou Desenvolvendo uma Aplicação e minha ideia é colocar essa aplicação do menu enviar para do Windows. Já consegui colocar o start da Aplicação la, mas eu não consigo obter o caminho do arquivo.

Exemplo: tenho um Arquivo pdf no Desktop o usuário vai clicar em cima com o botão direito no Menu "Enviar Para" ele vai selecionar minha aplicação e eu teria que receber o caminho desse arquivo.

Olhando Algumas Aplicação que tem essa funcionalidade eles usar um código de no mapeamento da aplicação `/sendto:` Ex: Skype `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /sendto:`, mas já coloquei desta forma e não funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Acabei conseguindo resolver o problema.
Ia apagar o post, mas acho que pode ajudar alguém,

Em vez de criar um atalho para executar o seu programa, é necessário vc colocar o próprio .EXE
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora para vc receber o caminho do arquivo na sua aplicação desktop, eu vou colocar um post um link:[Abrir Programa com arrastando arquivo(PDF) e o mesmo recuperar o caminho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231636/abrir-programa-com-arrastando-arquivopdf-e-o-mesmo-recuperar-o-caminho)